# JQuery - Correct way to populate data in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
function getData(id) {
    $.getJSON('process.php?action=lookup&id='+id, parseInfo);       
    return false;
}

// Display data in form
function parseInfo(data) {  
  if (data.id > 0) {
    $('#txtaction').val('update');
    $('#txtbook_id').val(data.id);
  } else {
    $('#txtaction').val('');
    $('#txtbook_id').val('');
  }
}
```

Referring to the method above, is this the proper way to populate form fields?
Will it cause any problem when calling getData function if i have a long list of form fields to populate and attributes to change?

Thank you in advance for any comments!

Comment: I like it ... simple and clean.

Comment: Everything looks fine.

Comment: If you're going to make this form very large, I'd consider a form-backing library such as AngularJS which does much of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Actually I have more than 50 fields in my form, separated into few tab pages. If this is right, why here are times I need to refresh my page a few times to make all data finish populate all the fields in my form? Should I run setTimeout(getData, 0) in order to complete the population of data into my form?

Comment: This is an ideal use-case for AngularJS as it keeps your form up to date automatically based on a backing object which you can manipulate at will. It also updates your backing object with the contents of the form, so they always stay in sync!

Comment: Thanks Jeff! I'll try it out! Thanks everybody for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tweak I'd make is to avoid repeating the selectors and `val` calls, too easy to add a field and forget to update one half of the `if/else` or the other:

```
function parseInfo(data) {  
  var valid = data && data.id > 0;
  $('#txtaction').val(valid ? 'update' : '');
  $('#txtbook_id').val(valid ? data.id : '');
}
```

---

Side note: Doing this manually is fine for very small projects, but for anything of any size, you might look into any of the various MVC and MVVC tools or frameworks. There are many.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be correct. However keep in mind that JSON attribute names can't contain dashes so an alternate way to get around that problem would be:

```
if (data['id'] > 0) {
    $('#txtaction').val('update');
    $('#txtbook_id').val(data['id']);
} else {
   $('#txtaction').val('');
   $('#txtbook_id').val('');
}
```

Comment: *"keep in mind that JSON attribute names can't contain dashes"* A) Yes they can (if you mean JSON *property* names), but **JavaScript identifiers** cannot. B) `id` doesn't have any dashes in it.

Comment: The id was just an example it obviously does not contain dashes :)

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't know that it was an issue with Javascript. Thank you for that

Comment: It's not really an *issue*, it's just that the language has to have a way to know that `a-b` is a subtraction expression, not a property name. JavaScript and JSON property names can be any string (so `foo["a-b"] = 42;` is fine, but I think you know that), but the *IdentifierName* grammar production is more limited, so you can't use the dot notation and the literal form with some property names.